# ошибка во время присвоения lst.count(elem): TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

```
d = dir()
s = ''
with open('file.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        s+=line.strip()
lst = [i for i in s.split()]
for elem in lst:
    if elem in d:
        d[elem] = d.get(elem) + 1
    else:
        d[elem] = lst.count(elem)
print(max(d))
```

нужно считать текст и вывести самое часто используемое, а у меня такая ошибка. В алгоритме могут быть проблемы, но хочу разобраться в ошибке, не понимаю почему выдается такой иксепшин

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Используется Python 3.6

Comment: часто используемое слово*

Comment: Может стоит поменять `d = dir()` на `d = {}`?

Comment: Вы похоже хотите аналог: `Counter(word for line in file for word in line.split()).most_common(1)` реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в `d[elem]`, но появилась она из-за `d = dir()`.

Поясню:

- `dir()` возвращает список, у него индексация целочисленная, а в `elem` находилась строка, поэтому было исключение `TypeError`
- По поводу `d = dir()`, это похоже опечатка, и на самом деле там должно было быть `d = dict()`

Comment: блин, как не заметил((